# Auto submitting external form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

www.example.com/a.php has a form on it that when it is filled and submitted goes to www.example.com/b.php.

I wish to replicate the form that is on www.example.com/a.php and host on my site. When my hosted one is submitted I wish to capture the data myself and for it to be submitted to www.example.com/a.php, the user still needs to go to www.example.com/b.php.

I know how to capture the data myself so that part isn't an issue and I have been told that I should be able to accomplish the auto submission with javascript but as hard as I search I can't find a way of achieving this.

Even if someone can tell me what I need to use for this I'd be happy to try and work this out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own form submit locally to your own postback, then recreate a dummy form which auto-posts to the real site:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('myform').submit()">
<form id="myform" action="http://myurl.tld/target" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="yourchoice" value="anything">
  <input type="submit" value="Go for it!">
</form>
</body>
```